# how to format json Array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, asp.net-ajax

How to convert a 2D array to json array and send to a view using ajax.

I used `return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symboltable2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

to convert it to json and return. The problem is json string contains double quotes to the beginning and end as `"[["A","B"],["C","D"]]"`. In order to deseralize this, I need to get rid of double quotes add curly brackets to the end and beginning.

But I need is to convert it to a json array like `[["A","B"],["C","D"]]`
any ideas how to do this?

Comment: what is `symboltable2`?

Comment: @Backs 2d array name.

Comment: I mean, what data does it have?

Comment: @Backs like 

 " [
        [
          "1",
          "2",
           "2",
          "2",
          "2",
        ],
        [
          "2",
          "Rou",
          "2",
         "5",
          "2",
        ],
        [
          "2",
         "2",
         "9",
           "2",
         "2",
        ] ] "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are double-serializing the array, which would explain the extra quotes.  Both the Json.Net `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method and the `Json()` MVC method perform serialization.  You should use only one of them.

So, either remove the call to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and let `Json()` handle the serialization...

```
return Json(symboltable2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

or, if you prefer to use Json.Net, then use the `Content()` method instead of the `Json()` method to return the result:

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symboltable2), "application/json");
```

If you use the second approach, you'll also need to make sure the return type of your controller method is either `ContentResult` or `ActionResult` (as opposed to `JsonResult`).

Comment: God you just saved me. thats was exactly the issue.  return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symboltable2), "application/json");  did it well . THANKS A LOT MATE.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the quotes using `String.Trim`.

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '"' };
string json = Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symboltable2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
string result = json.Trim(charsToTrim);
```

Comment: thanks  but its not working . array is like " [ [ "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", ], [ "2", "Rou", "2", "5", "2", ], [ "2", "2", "9", "2", "2", ] ] "
only first and the last should get rid of. but even its not working with trim.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want to get rid of quotes and braces (curly brackets). This is pretty simple to do by using `.Remove()`

```
string json = Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(symboltable2), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);;
json = json.Remove(json.Substring(0, 1));
json = json.Remove(json.Substring(json.Length - 1, 1));
return json;
```

Comment: @mihir no actualy this data is to jquery datatables so it wont accept data in side {[[]]}  or "[[]]"   . both sould be avoided in this case.

Comment: @RangaN so you’re wanting to use .remove(). See my updated answer.